# SQL Server 2012: how to create computed column with a formula based column within the same dataset?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Using SQL Server 2012. I have a table that looks similar to this (very simplified):

```
ID|Formula|A1|A2|A3|A4|A5
--+-------+--+--+--+--+--
1 |A1+A2  |1 |2 |3 |4 |5
2 |A3+A4  |6 |7 |8 |9 |10
```

`ID` is unique, A1 to A5 are numeric, Formula is a `varchar`.

I need a computed column that uses the formula in the column `[Formula]` to add the columns as noted in it, so add the values of [A1] + [A2] for example, so the result set would look like this:

```
ID|Formula|Result
--+-------+------
1 |A1+A2  |3     
2 |A3+A4  |17 


select [ID], [Formula], xxx as [Result] 
from dbo.ThatTable
```

I just don't know how to do this (if its even possible), instead of xxx to parse the `[Formula]` column and use the Information on how to add (or subtract, multiply) do whatever mathematical operation with the [A1] to [A5] columns.

There are too many different formulas to get around this with a 'case when then.

Comment: Could you have other expressions other than addition? For example `'a1-a2'`, `'a3*a5'` or even `'a2^a4'`? If so, what expressions could there be? Could you have more than 2 in a single expressions, i.e. `'a1+a2+a3-a5'`?

Comment: Yes, there are a few with 5 or more in the formula, and it uses add, substract, mulitply and divide.

Comment: Yuck... If it was just addition it would be *so* much easier... Some really ugly dynamic SQL it is. let's see what we can do. Give me a while.

Comment: As an aside, *why* do you need to do this?  What is the source data, process and required output?

Comment: I would use a CLR function that parses and evaluates the expression using the JInt Javascript Interpreter: https://github.com/sebastienros/jint

Comment: Oh and do you need to worry about parentheses?  Could you have a formula such as `(A1 + A2) * ((A1 + (A2 - A3)) - A4)`?

Comment: This is getting messier and messier... >_<

Comment: @iamdave The request came to show the calculated value of the formula within the same dataset as the formula is, and I thought i might be missing something obiously simple here, since the formula is right there, so are the values, and for example with a case when I could get the values, there are just too many for that. I can't work with a temp table either sadly, results has to come from a single select :( On your second question, sadly, yes, a few have parentheses.

Comment: @Larnu yeah :( If this isn't possbile with a simple command, I can see where the data from the table comes from and work something out. The reason I posted here is because I thought I was missing something obvious really.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming all formulas are stored correctly and will give the correct output 'as is', that you can use `exec sp_executesql` and ***you are 100% sure you are totally protected against potential sql injection***, the following piece of hella nasty code does what you need it to (I think) in one dynamic statement with no loops or table inserts.

Be aware that this calculates *every* formula for *every* row so may well perform horrendously on larger datasets:

```
declare @t table(ID int, Formula varchar(50), A1 float, A2 float, A3 float, A4 float, A5 float);
insert into @t values
 (1,'A1+A2',1,2,3,4,5)
,(2,'A3+A4',6,7,8,9,10)
,(3,'A3/A4',6,7,8,9,10)
,(4,'A3+(A4*A4)',6,7,8,9,10);

-- I have included the table variable definition in the dynamic sql because a table variable will be outside the scope of the dynamic execution, whereas your regular table won't be.
declare @sql nvarchar(max) = 
'declare @t table(ID int, Formula varchar(50), A1 float, A2 float, A3 float, A4 float, A5 float);
insert into @t values
 (1,''A1+A2'',1,2,3,4,5)
,(2,''A3+A4'',6,7,8,9,10)
,(3,''A3/A4'',5,4,3,2,1)
,(4,''A3+(A4*A4)'',10,9,8,7,6);
'
+
'select t.ID, t.Formula, t.A1, t.A2, t.A3, t.A4, t.A5, c.Value
from(
  select ID, Formula, A1, A2, A3, A4, A5' + stuff((
      select ',' + Formula + ' as [' + cast(ID as nvarchar(10)) + ']'
      from @t
      for xml path('')
      ),1,0,'') + '
    from @t
    ) as t
    cross apply(values' + 
        stuff((
        select ',(t.ID,' + cast(ID as nvarchar(10)) + ',[' + cast(ID as nvarchar(10)) + '])'
        from @t
        for xml path('')
        ),1,1,'') + ') as c(ID, Calc, Value)
  where t.ID = c.ID
      and c.ID = c.Calc;'
    ;

--print @sql  -- To output the generated script uncomment this line
exec sp_executesql @sql;
```

## Output

```
+----+------------+----+----+----+----+----+-------+
| ID | Formula    | A1 | A2 | A3 | A4 | A5 | Value |
+----+------------+----+----+----+----+----+-------+
|  1 | A1+A2      |  1 |  2 |  3 |  4 |  5 |     3 |
|  2 | A3+A4      |  6 |  7 |  8 |  9 | 10 |    17 |
|  3 | A3/A4      |  5 |  4 |  3 |  2 |  1 |   1.5 |
|  4 | A3+(A4*A4) | 10 |  9 |  8 |  7 |  6 |    57 |
+----+------------+----+----+----+----+----+-------+
```

and a [working example](https://rextester.com/ZFG25532).

Comment: Hello, good solution. Could u please explain why this solution is safe against injection attacks?

Comment: Very thorough, thank you for your help. I can work with this.

Comment: @ErayBalkanli  It isn't, in my answer I have stated that this is only a suitable answer *assuming* they are *already* safe from injection, for example if the data being run on has been thoroughly checked before manual execution

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you can do this in a computed column, since the only way I see to do this is with Dynamic SQL, and that can't be used in a UDF.

As such, I think the closest you can get to something similar is to use a TRIGGER to populate a regular column.

Answer (score 0):

Great question!

Here is a dynamic solution for you:

```
create table #temp (id int, formula varchar(30), A1 int, A2 int, A3 int)
insert into #temp values (1,'A1+A2',1,2,3), (2,'A2+A3',5,8,9), (3,'A1+A3',15,28,39)

--need a loop for each id, save results in temp table
create table #result (id int, formula varchar(30), Total int)
declare @IdCounter int = 1

while (@IdCounter <= (select count(*) from #temp))
begin

    --get formula of id.
    declare @x nvarchar(30) = (select t.formula from #temp t where t.id = @IdCounter) 

    --use formula dynamically
    declare @sql nvarchar(max) = '
    insert into #result
    select t.id,t.formula,(select '+@x+' from #temp t2 where t2.id = t.id)
    from #temp t
    where t.id = '+cast(@IdCounter as nvarchar(10))+'
    '
    EXECUTE sp_executesql @sql

    set @IdCounter = @IdCounter + 1;
end
select * from #result

drop table #temp
drop table #result
```

Additional info: You don't need for this example, but for the future, if you need to split the formula and receive the columns will be used in the calculation for each id, you can use:

```
SELECT id,Split.a.value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') DATA
into #temp2
FROM
(
    SELECT t.id, CAST('<X>'+REPLACE(t.formula, '+', '</X><X>')+'</X>' AS XML) AS String From #temp t
) AS A
CROSS APPLY String.nodes('/X') AS Split(a);
```

Comment: The problem with this, which i was *trying* to avoid with what i was wording on, is that it's open to injection. This trusts that the expression in the column `formula` is not only valid, but no malicious; which is something I personally will never trust.

Comment: Yes, the value of formula must be valid and true for this solution. I am not sure how to check a validation function to check the validity of it, the OP should add at least an IF-ELSE function. Any advice from you for that? @Larnu

Comment: Not without a lot of time and effort. I'm not a fan of solutions like the OP has here in truth.

Comment: @Eray: Thank you for the your help and the script. The formulas are valid, in this particular scenario this is 100% guaranteed.

Comment: @ThomasFüllenbach You are welcome, I'd appreciate if you select the answer as the correct one by clicking the tick on the left. Glad to help.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best approach is to use SQLCLR, because:

- It's SQL Injection immune
- Allows you to define a computed column
- The computed column is persistable.
- You can even create an index on the persisted column
- Performance is good because the formula evaluation only occurs on data modification and Jint Javascript engine is very fast for small scripts.

Open Visual Studio, create a class library project targeting .NET Framework 4.0 called Formulas.

Open Nuget Package Manager Console and execute the following:

```
Install-Package Jint
```

Add a new class to the project called `UserDefinedFunctions` with the following content:

```
using System.Data.SqlTypes;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Server;

public partial class UserDefinedFunctions
{
    [SqlFunction(Name = "EvaluateFormula", DataAccess = DataAccessKind.None, IsDeterministic =true, SystemDataAccess = SystemDataAccessKind.None)]
    public static SqlDouble EvaluateFormula(SqlString formula, SqlDouble a1, SqlDouble a2, SqlDouble a3, SqlDouble a4, SqlDouble a5)
    {
        if (formula.IsNull) return SqlDouble.Null;
        var engine = new Jint.Engine();
        if (!a1.IsNull) engine.SetValue("A1", a1.Value);
        if (!a2.IsNull) engine.SetValue("A2", a2.Value);
        if (!a3.IsNull) engine.SetValue("A3", a3.Value);
        if (!a4.IsNull) engine.SetValue("A4", a4.Value);
        if (!a5.IsNull) engine.SetValue("A5", a5.Value);
        try
        {
            var value = engine.Execute(formula.Value).GetCompletionValue().AsNumber();
            return new SqlDouble(value);
        }
        catch
        {
            return SqlDouble.Null;
        }
    }
}
```

Build the project. Open bin folder, copy Jint.dll and Formulas.dll to the SQL Server data folder.

Execute the following T-SQL script:

```
EXEC sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1
EXEC sp_configure 'clr enabled', 1

RECONFIGURE
GO


ALTER DATABASE Tests SET TRUSTWORTHY ON

GO

USE Tests
GO

CREATE ASSEMBLY Jint
FROM 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\Jint.dll'
WITH PERMISSION_SET = UNSAFE
GO
CREATE ASSEMBLY Formulas
FROM 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\Formulas.dll'
WITH PERMISSION_SET = UNSAFE
GO


CREATE FUNCTION EvaluateFormula
(
    @formula nvarchar(4000),
    @a1 float,
    @a2 float,
    @a3 float,
    @a4 float,
    @a5 float
)
RETURNS float
AS EXTERNAL NAME Formulas.UserDefinedFunctions.EvaluateFormula

GO

SELECT dbo.EvaluateFormula(N'A1 * A2 * (A3 + A4)', 2, 3, 1, 1, 10)

GO


CREATE TABLE Formulas
(
    Id int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    Formula nvarchar(4000),
    A1 float,
    A2 float,
    A3 float,
    A4 float,
    A5 float,
    Value AS (dbo.EvaluateFormula(Formula, A1, A2, A3, A4, A5)) PERSISTED
)

GO

CREATE INDEX ix_Formulas_Value ON Formulas(Value)

GO

INSERT INTO Formulas VALUES
(1,'A1+A2',1,2,3,4,5),
(2,'A3+A4',6,7,8,9,10),
(3,'A3/A4',6,7,8,9,10),
(4,'A3+(A4*A4)',6,7,8,9,10);

GO

SELECT * FROM Formulas
```

Comment: This looks interesting, thank you for taking the time to write that out. Unfortunately, this is not an option here, I only have a SQL query fired off by the application to work with. I will pass this on to the Devs though. I am just in Data Analytics.